# Howto: Connect dynamically created views (non-singleton forms) to a singleton controller with Spring.NET config file?

Tags: model-view-controller, event-handling, spring.net

I have a piece of code that create Windows Forms dynamically at run-time using the lookup-method tag approach in Spring.NET. Basically what I have is a factory class to create any number of Forms, see config file snippet below.

```
<object id="frmListView" type="GUI.View.ListView, MMM" singleton="false">
    <property name="MdiParent" ref="frmMainForm" />
</object>

<object id="frmListViewController" type="Controller.View.ListView, MMM">
    <listener event="Search" method="frmListView_Search">
        <ref object="frmListView"/>
    </listener>
</object>

<object id="frmListViewFactory" type="GUI.ListViewFactory, MMM">
    <lookup-method name="createView" object="frmListView" />
</object>
```

The problem is that since the `frmListView` is created dynamically it seems like the `listener`-tag doesn't bind, i.e. the Search-event will not be bound to any event listener. Obviously I can solve this by doing the binding in code but I would like to know if there is any way to do it in the context file?

I find it a bit strange since the whole idea with the `lookup-method` factory is to have the created `frmListView` instance Spring-aware and it is to some extent, i.e. the `MdiParent` property is set as expected but apparently the listener reference in the singleton `frmListViewController` is not resolved.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, Ola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this in an xml config, actually I'm not even sure if it is possible at all in xml. But I can explain why your approach doesn't work:

With this configuration, you create a singleton `frmListViewController`, that subscribes to the `Search` event from a `frmListView`. This `frmListView` is requested from the container and because it's a prototype (non singleton), a new `ListView` instance is created.

Your `frmListViewController` will *only* listen to `Search` events from this `ListView` instance, because, well, that's the way it's configured. The listener reference is resolved, but it resolves to a `ListView` instance you didn't expect.

You'll see that a single `ListView` instance is created once the container is initialized, as part of the creation of `frmListViewFactory`. You can test this (for instance) by setting a breakpoint in the `ListView` constructor and run a program similar to this:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IApplicationContext ctx = new XmlApplicationContext("objects.xml");

        Console.WriteLine("Container initialized ... ");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You'll observe that a new `ListView` is created, without the `frmListViewFactory`'s `CreateView` method being called.

BTW, the purpose of lookup method injection [is *not* to make `frmListView` and `frmListViewFactory` aware of their container](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-method-injection-lookup).